# How to pass an array from a parent component to child component using props in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-props

I want to paas "subjects" array from **SubjectsScreen** to **MarkAttendanceScreen** and display the array items as a FlatList.

**Parent Component**

```
export default class SubjectsScreen extends Component {
    state = {
      subjects: ["A", "B"]
    };

    render() {
      return (
          ...
          <MarkAttendanceScreen subjectsArray={this.state.subjects} />
      );
    }
}
```

**Child Component**

```
export default class MarkAttendanceScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        subjects: []
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({ subjects: this.props.subjectsArray });
    }

    render() {
      return (   
        <FlatList>
            { this.props.subjects.map((item, key)=>(
                <Text key={key}> { item } </Text>)
            )}
        </FlatList>
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: But why you are not using flat-list props like data, renderItem etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using props was giving error when using FlatList with map.
Works fine when extracting value directly from AsyncStorage.

```
export default class MarkAttendanceScreen extends Component {

  state = {
    subjects: [],
    text: ""
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Subjects.all(subjects => this.setState({ subjects: subjects || [] }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={ this.state.subjects}
          renderItem={({item}) => {
            return (
              <View>
                  <Text> { item.text } </Text>
              </View>
            )
          }}
          keyExtractor={ (item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

let Subjects = {
  convertToArrayOfObject(subjects, callback) {
    return callback(
    subjects ? subjects.split("\n").map((subject, i) => ({ key: i, text: subject })) : []
    );
  },
  convertToStringWithSeparators(subjects) {
    return subjects.map(subject => subject.text).join("\n");
  },
  all(callback) {
    return AsyncStorage.getItem("SUBJECTS", (err, subjects) =>
    this.convertToArrayOfObject(subjects, callback)
    );
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the same key name that you used while passing down data to child component e.g. in your case you used key `subjectsArray` here and You don't need to store this first in state and then use unless you want to update it later.

```
<MarkAttendanceScreen subjectsArray={this.state.subjects} />
```

So in your child component, it will be

```
<FlatList>
   {this.props.subjectsArray.map((item, key)=>(
       <Text key={key}> { item } </Text>
   ))}
</FlatList>
```

Comment: but its not compulsory to directly use the same name, he is by the way assigning the value to the state after the component has mount. Their is some other issue.

Comment: After executing this code, it shows 
```TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.subjectsArray.map')```

Comment: @AyushiKeshri What's your view on this? I am comfortable with any way, just need to print those array elements.

Answer (score 0):

`this.props.subjects` does not exist, but you did set the state in `componentDidMount`. In the FlatList use `this.state.subject.map`.

```
render() {
  return (   
    <FlatList>
        { this.state.subjects.map((item, key)=>(
             // ^here
            <Text key={key}> { item } </Text>)
        )}
    </FlatList>
  );
}
```

Comment: After executing this code, it shows ```TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.subjects.map')```

Comment: Dang it looks like FlatList requires some properties to display info, like data and renderItem. Glad you got it figured out in your answer, or see cschultz1272 update.

Answer (score 0):

D. Smith is correct, you need to change that line to `this.state.subjects.map` But could also just remove the state variable from the Child Component and use the array directly from props.

```
export default class MarkAttendanceScreen extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (   
      <FlatList>
          { this.props.subjectsArray.map((item, key)=>(
              <Text key={key}> { item } </Text>)
          )}
      </FlatList>
    );
  }
}
```

### Update:

Flatlists need to be defined like this:

```
<FlatList
    data={ this.props.subjectsArray }
    renderItem={({item}) => {
        return (
             <Text> { item } </Text>)
        )
    }}  
   keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
/>
```

or you can use it the way you have it and remove the flatlist like:

```
return this.props.subjectsArray.map((item, key)=>(
        <Text key={key}> { item } </Text>)
       )}
```

Comment: After executing this code, it shows ```TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.subjectsArray.map')```